# creation of new project in ibm-bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

Why we can't longer create a new Project in IBM bluemix?
I'm getting below message

> "You can no longer create projects, as JazzHub is retired. Create a toolchain instead"

Can't create a project without toolchain?

Answer (score 1):

Jazzhub projects are retired, see here for more info: https://developer.ibm.com/devops-services/2017/04/18/upgrading-jazzhub-projects-bluemix-continuous-delivery-toolchains/